# Django WebApp configuration on CentOS7 using Apache mod_wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache

I have developed a simple website using python django web framework. I am trying to deploy my website on apache mod_wsgi, but it is throwing 500 Internal server error.

My project environment details are here.

Python version: Python 3.6.8

Django version: 3.0.5

Database: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30

Operating system: CentOS7

HTTPD version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

My Apache configuration file is below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName 192.168.25.128
ServerAlias nwaytech.co.in
Alias /favicon.ico /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/static/images/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/media/
Alias /static/ /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/static/
Alias /static/ /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/temlpates/

<Directory /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/templates>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/nwayapp/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess nwayapp python-home=/opt/pydjwebpro/  python-path= /opt/pydjwebpro/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup nwayapp

<Directory /opt/pydjwebpro/nwayapp/nwayapp/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have installed mod_wsgi using pip in my virtual environment, I have to install httpd-devel packages.

Could you anyone help, Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error 500 means that your code raise some error, you should read the /var/log/apache2/errors.log and post the Traceback

Comment: @lorenzo_campanile, I have checked and found "ImportError: No module named site"  error log,  but it does not help to fix the problem.

Comment: @lorenzo_campanile, I have also found this log **AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations.** It showing Python 2.7.5. But i am using python3.6. I guess apache/httpd not able to read python3 modules.

Comment: mhh... you have 2 critical problems here: 1. "ImportError: No module named site", you should have the partent directory of site in the PYTHONPATH (you should set the PYTHONPATH via WSGI in your case), 2. mod_wsgi is using the wrong version of Python, try using a virtualenv

Comment: @lorenzo_campanile, I have tried with the help of virtual but does not help. Getting the same error when tried with another machine that was installed python3 alone.

Comment: @Hi lorenzo_campanile, I fixed this issue by including project directory path into wsgi.py  **path = '/opt/pydjprojectsd/nwaytechpydjpro/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)** .  Yes, I changed my porject name this time.